# Delete entries with dependencies to other entries in a java stucture

Tags: java, algorithm, types

Assume I have following structure: (for example in a JSON)

```
...
{event: Web, action:Video, timestamp:1320},
{event: Web, action:Play, timestamp: 1320},
{event: Web, action:Download, timestamp: 1320},
{event: Web, action:Play, timestamp: 1321}
...
```

Now I want to iterate of the structure and delete all rows with “action:Play”,where an action:Download with the same timestamp happens.

So the result would look like:

```
...
{event: Web, action:Video, timestamp:1320},
{event: Web, action:Download, timestamp: 1320},
{event: Web, action:Play, timestamp: 1321}
...
```

I´m not sure, who I should realize this in Java. My question is here: With type (List, Map, …)  and with Algo should I use for this problem?

Comment: What have you tried doing? And what exactly are these "structures"? Are they classes?

Comment: Thats the question, which structure should i use there?

Comment: I have only one Suggestion: learn by doing. If you have no idea how to start with this problem, then find an easier problem to solve first.

Comment: We need to know what you want to do to answer. You want ot put them ijnto, say, a List, but a List holds and Object, so what it the Object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a class with the variables like *timestamp*

Here is an example:

```
static class  MediaPlayer{
        String event;
        String action;
        int timestamp;
        public MediaPlayer(String event, String action,int timestamp){
            this.event=event;
            this.action=action;
            this.timestamp=timestamp;
        }
        public String getEvent(){
            return event;
        }
        public String getAction(){
            return action;
        }
        public int getTimeStamp(){
            return timestamp;
        }
    }
```

Then in main you can create a list of *ClassName Objects*. Iterate through them and remove them using removeAll() method.

```
public static void main(String args[]){

        List<MediaPlayer> mp=new ArrayList<>();
        List<MediaPlayer> remove=new ArrayList<>();//I have made this for demostration purpose that you could even collect these objects somewhere and do something with them!

        mp.add(new MediaPlayer("web","Video",1320));
        mp.add(new MediaPlayer("web","Play",1320));
        mp.add(new MediaPlayer("web","Download",1320));
        mp.add(new MediaPlayer("web","Play",1321));

        mp.forEach((it)->{
            System.out.println("Event: "+it.getEvent()+" Action: "+it.getAction()+" TimeStamp: "+it.getTimeStamp());
        });

       Iterator<MediaPlayer> iter = mp.iterator();
       Iterator<MediaPlayer> iter1 = mp.iterator();
       for(MediaPlayer it:mp){
           for(MediaPlayer itr:mp){
               if(it.getAction().equals("Download") && it.getTimeStamp()==itr.getTimeStamp() && itr.getAction().equals("Play")){
                   remove.add(itr);// I add the objects to be removed in remove list first. This way I will even have the list of deleted objects
               }
           }
       }
       mp.removeAll(remove);//Then finally I remove them from main list

       System.out.println("\n");
        mp.forEach((it)->{
            System.out.println("Event: "+it.getEvent()+" Action: "+it.getAction()+" TimeStamp: "+it.getTimeStamp());
        });
}
```